# Laravel API Handle Exception Validation

Tags: laravel, api, validation

I am handling an API exception of validation errors throwing exception `Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException`. It returns an exception `$this->convertValidationExceptionToResponse($exception, $request)`.Validation Exception does not show the error message.
Trying `$exception->getMessage()` from the output of $this->convertValidationExceptionToResponse($exception, $request); throws error.

How to send the error messages of validation in the response ?

```
namespace App\Exceptions;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler as ExceptionHandler;
use Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException;
use Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException;
use Throwable;
use Exception;

class Handler extends ExceptionHandler
{

public function render($request, Throwable $exception)
{

    if ($request->is('api/*')) {
         return $this->handleException($request, $exception);
    }

    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}

public function handleException($request, Exception $exception)
{
    if (method_exists($exception, 'getStatusCode')) {
        $statusCode = $exception->getStatusCode();
    } else {
        $statusCode = 500;
    }

    if ($exception instanceof MethodNotAllowedHttpException) {
        $response['message'] = 'Method Not Allowed';
        $response['status'] = false;
        $response['status_code'] = $statusCode;
        return response()->json($response, $statusCode);
    }

    if ($exception instanceof NotFoundHttpException) {
        $response['message'] = 'Not Found';
        $response['status'] = false;
        $response['status_code'] = $statusCode;            
        return response()->json($response, $statusCode);
    }

    if ($exception instanceof HttpException) {
        $response['message'] = $exception->getMessage();
        $response['status'] = false;
        $response['status_code'] = $statusCode;            
        return response()->json($response, $statusCode);
    }
    if ($exception instanceof AuthenticationException) {
        $exception = $this->unauthenticated($request, $exception);
        $response['message'] = 'Authentication Error';
        $response['status'] = false;
        $response['status_code'] = $exception->getStatusCode();            
        return response()->json($response, $statusCode);             
    }
    if ($exception instanceof ValidationException) {
        $exception = $this->convertValidationExceptionToResponse($exception, $request);
        $response['message'] = 'Validation Error';
        $response['status'] = false;
        $response['status_code'] = $exception->getStatusCode();            
        return response()->json($response, $statusCode);            
    }        
    if (config('app.debug')) {
        $response['trace'] = $exception->getTrace();
        $response['code'] = $exception->getCode();
        $response['status'] = false;
        $response['status_code'] = $statusCode;
        return response()->json($response, $statusCode);            
    }
    $response['message'] = $exception->getMessage();
    $response['status'] = false;
    $response['status_code'] = $statusCode;
    return response()->json($response, $statusCode);

}
```

Comment: if you send your requests with the accepts header for json you would get json responses back

Comment: My question is How to send validation errors in the response?

Comment: the validation errors would be part of that json response, key named `errors`, if you send the correct headers ... `convertValidationExceptionToResponse` will use `invalidJson` instead of `invalid` so it would be a json response of the errors not a redirect response ... if you want to be building your own response then you can get the errors from the exception itself `$e->errors()`

Comment: I tried this `$response['errors'] = $exception->errors()`; it is throwing error message

Comment: btw, the exception handler is already setup to return JSON responses you don't need to be rebuilding this functionality